# Count by column

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have the following data:

[image: data]

And I want to know how often each value exists in each column. So my preferred output should look like this:

[image: output]

I'd be really grateful, if anybody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag. Also, what have you tried so far? Show your effort..

Comment: Please paste text, not images. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I haven't tried much yet, because i don't really have a clue

Comment: I have multiple columns that all have numbers between 1 and 5 in them. I'd like to make a Matrix that shows, how often each number appears in each column

Comment: And again: What DBMS are you using? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: sorry forgot, I use Oracle

Answer (score 1):

```
with
     inputs ( a, b, c, d ) as (
       select 1, 2, 1, 2 from dual union all
       select 1, 2, 2, 2 from dual union all
       select 2, 1, 3, 3 from dual union all
       select 3, 3, 2, 4 from dual union all
       select 4, 4, 2, 5 from dual union all
       select 5, 5, 5, 5 from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select grade,
       count(case when a = grade then 0 end) as a,
       count(case when b = grade then 0 end) as b,
       count(case when c = grade then 0 end) as c,
       count(case when d = grade then 0 end) as d
from   inputs cross join (select level as grade from dual connect by level <= 5)
group by grade
order by grade
;

     GRADE          A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          1          1          0
         2          1          2          3          2
         3          1          1          1          1
         4          1          1          0          1
         5          1          1          1          2
```

NOTE: This is essentially the same as MT0's solution, but both the unpivoting and the pivoting are done the "old way" (as they were done before PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators were introduced in Oracle 11.1).

Comment: The biggest difference with this compared to `UNPIVOT`/`PIVOT` is that you need to know the number/range of values in the table with this method so that the `LEVEL <= 5` clause generates sufficient rows.

Comment: @MT0 - Right - in fact my "NOTE" is not entirely correct, since I don't really unpivot, I still keep the original rows in place.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird table structure and/or task. You may want to think over your database design. Anyway ...

```
select 
  num, 
  coalesce(agga.cnt, 0) as a,
  coalesce(aggb.cnt, 0) as b,
  coalesce(aggc.cnt, 0) as c,
  coalesce(aggd.cnt, 0) as d
from            (select a as num, count(*) as cnt from mytable group by a) agga
full outer join (select b as num, count(*) as cnt from mytable group by b) aggb using(num)
full outer join (select c as num, count(*) as cnt from mytable group by c) aggc using(num)
full outer join (select d as num, count(*) as cnt from mytable group by d) aggd using(num)
order by num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT` then `PIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4efe/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( a, b, c, d ) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 5, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT( value FOR name IN ( A, B, C, D ) )
PIVOT  ( COUNT(1) FOR name IN ( 'A' AS A, 'B' AS B, 'C' AS C, 'D' AS D ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4efe/1/0)**:

```
| VALUE | A | B | C | D |
|-------|---|---|---|---|
|     1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|     2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
|     4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
|     5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
|     3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
```